# legal limit for a tender in a B2B cooperation

Tags: legal-tender

Is there a legal limit, above which all B2B transactions must be carried out by tender?  (And below which there is no need for a tender, and a company can use the services of any company of their choice?)

If so, what is the amount?

I am interested in mostly EU countries.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking here. Could you please elaborate further?

Comment: Is there a financial limit from which there has to be a strict selection procedure given by the law about which company to buy 200 cars from, and below such a financial limit there wouldn't have to be such a strict selection procedure, e.g. when buying one window?

Comment: What jurisdiction is this under? And in this B2B transaction... Is one of the businesses a government entity?

Comment: If it is a government entity... Than yes, most likely there is a law... If it is not than it depends on where these businesses are... More protectionist countries do have laws that might come in effect.

Comment: I have tried to put this question in understandable English (and prevent it being closed).  If you feel I have misrepresented your meaning, please roll back my changes and [edit] it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

### Purchase by tender is optional

Businesses can and do by from each other on many basis - they may pay a list price, they may place an order without knowing the price, they may ask for quotations (from one or many suppliers), they may negotiate a price, they may hold an auction, they may hold a formal tender process.

There is no law that says which they may use in what circumstances. If they want to have a formal tender for the supply on 1 paperclip, they can. If they want to order 78 A380 Airbuses without agreeing an upfront price, they can.